# How to add a project to other project having almost same features

Tags: ios, merge, targets

I am having an app named **ABC** which is in English and another clone of same app in French. Right now they are behaving as two different projects. What I want is, merge them in one project and at the time of import or execution, i decide that which target should be chosen.

I have managed a file named `constants.h`in which all my strings are kept. I just change this file and get another app in different language.

Comment: Why you are not using localization?

Comment: You should use localization. look this example http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: I cannot use it because some features are different in different clones.

Answer (score 0):

**Localization is the process of adapting a product or service to a particular language, culture, and desired local "look-and-feel.**

check below tutorials, it will be helpful for you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: I cannot use localization. Because there are some different features in other apps